# creating new sheet and moving sheets between spreadsheet in google docs

Tags: google-docs, google-sheets, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I have 2 requirements:

1) I want to create a new sheet from existing sheet in current spreadsheet programmatically

2) I want to copy one sheet from one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet programmatically

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have not specified the environment/language. I think the easiest way to do this is using [Apps Script](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/) as it's built-in in Google Spreadsheets.

Here is a sample code that does this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SheetName');
  sheet.copyTo(ss).setName('NewName'); //copy to the same spreadsheet.
  //get a different spreadsheet (you can get its id in the url)
  var os = SpreadsheetApp.openById('any-spreadsheet-key-that-you-can-edit');
  //copy sourceSheet from one spreadsheet to another
  sheet.copyTo(os).setName('AnotherName');
}
```

To run this, just open the spreadsheet with the sheet you want to copy, click the menu Tools > Script editor.. Paste the code, Save and Run > myFunction

Comment: Thanks for this. I could not find a way to move worksheets between spreadsheets via the Google Spreadsheets API in C#. I had to implement an Apps script, and use the remote execution API to run it. It's not super fast (5-10 seconds), but it works.